# Subtracting two values from SQL queries (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to subtract the value of count `routeid` from `capacity`.
It should be 350 - 1, I have no luck doing it code below

```
(SELECT CAPACITY 
 FROM PLANE 
 WHERE SERIALNO = 'FH-FBT') -  
(SELECT COUNT(ROUTEID)
 FROM RESERVATION 
 WHERE ROUTEID = 'FBN001')
```

Comment: What is the intended logic here?  The first query generally will return a _table_, while the second query will return a _number_.  Please add sample data.

Comment: Please do not roll back edits that objectively improve the post, such as by adding code formatting. Instead, read [the help pages on formatting](/help/formatting) and be sure to format your posts properly yourself when posting your next question.

Comment: Hi the capacity would be the how many seats the plane has , which is 350 

the count gives me the number of people who booked the plane 

so i am trying to get the number of seats left. 

so if i am following your comment i can't subtract a count value from a table result? how do i go about accomplishing it then?

Comment: What does "I have no luck" mean? Do you get a result (but is wrong), or did you get an error (if so, which one?), or ...? Some sample data might help us help you, as well as full code you used because the one you posted can't work "as is".

Comment: You cannot evaluate standalone SQL expressions, they have to be `select`ed from somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query result is a table. In your case you have two query results, and the tables consist of one row and column each. You subtract one result set from the other. I.e. you have a statement that is `dataset - dataset` or, as these are scalar queries `value - value`. The DBMS, however does not know what to do with this, because you haven't told it to *select* the result.

With a capacity of 350 and a reservation count of 50 you have a statement like this:

```
350 - 50
```

But a proper statement would look like this in standard SQL:

```
select 350 - 50;
```

And as Oracle always needs a table to select from:

```
select 350 - 50 from dual;
```

The whole query:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT capacity FROM plane WHERE serialno = 'FH-FBT') -  
  (SELECT COUNT(routeid) FROM reservation WHERE routed = 'FBN001')
FROM DUAL;
```

Another option to select the result would be to cross join the two values / subquery results:

```
SELECT capacity - reserved
FROM
  (SELECT capacity FROM plane WHERE serialno = 'FH-FBT')
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(routeid) AS reserved FROM reservation WHERE routed = 'FBN001');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, if I understood correctly what you want:

```
SELECT CAPACITY -(SELECT COUNT(ROUTEID)
 FROM RESERVATION 
 WHERE ROUTEID = 'FBN001') 
 FROM PLANE 
 WHERE SERIALNO = 'FH-FBT'
```

or

```
SELECT capacity -reserved_count
    FROM PLANE 
     WHERE SERIALNO = 'FH-FBT'  join
    (SELECT COUNT(ROUTEID)reserved_count
     FROM RESERVATION 
     WHERE ROUTEID = 'FBN001')
```